# Question on Python Function to capaitalize letters at even position

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am able to perform the capitalization function using the below for loop and enumerate function.

```
wordlist = list(word)
for i,v in enumerate(wordlist):
    if i%2 != 0:
        wordlist[i] = v.upper()
    else:
        wordlist[i] = v.lower()
        word2 = "".join(wordlist)
print(word2)
```

However when I try to put it into the function in python, I am not able to reproduce the same result as above:

```
def myfunc(*word):
    wordlist = list(word)
    for i,v in enumerate(wordlist):
        if i%2 != 0:
            wordlist[i] = v.upper()
        else:
            wordlist[i] = v.lower()
            word = "".join(wordlist)
    return (word)
```

Can anyone help me with my question?

Comment: `word` in in your function is a tuple because you are using *word and so `list(word)` is not returning what you expect from it. Do you need to pass multiple words in the function parameter?

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal Yup, it's returning `[word]`, and default it's `(word)`, because thats basically `*args`, from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)

Comment: Why did you use a `def myfunc(*word):` variable-length argument signature here?

Comment: Also, your `"".join(wordlist)` is indented too much.

Comment: @kindall Oh yeah, why not just at the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to unpack (`*`) that makes `word` equal to `(word,)` i.e. single element tuple:

```
def myfunc(word):
    wordlist = list(word)
    for i,v in enumerate(wordlist):
        if i%2 != 0:
            wordlist[i] = v.upper()
        else:
            wordlist[i] = v.lower()
            word = "".join(wordlist)
    return (word)
```

Or easier:

```
def myfunc(word):
    word=list(word.lower())
    for i,v in enumerate(word):
        if i%2 != 0:
            word[i] = v.upper()
    return ''.join(word)
```

Better:

```
def myfunc(word):
    word=list(word.lower())
    word[1::2]=map(str.upper,word[1::2])
    return ''.join(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Easier and simpler approach**

```
 def func(word):
        result = ""
        for i in range(len(word)):
            if i % 2 == 0:
                result += word[i].upper()
            else:
                result += word[i]
        return result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       word = "prasanna"
       def myfunc(word):
          word=list(word.lower())
          for i,v in enumerate(word):
               if i%2 != 0:
                 word[i] = v.upper()
          print  ''.join(word)
       myfunc(word)
```